# Call parent in Fragment android

Tags: android

There are a lot of fragment in the activity of my project.
For example:
Now I have used begintransaction to intent from A to B fragment or C to B fragment, and in B fragment i have any button, and I click into it, it will be returned parent fragment.
Every one can help me a suggestion or advise.

Comment: Reason for downvote?
Duplicate? Include link if so.

Comment: sorry, but it's not possible, I tried all suggestion, but it's not working.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clearly state your problem. If your English is not good enough, try providing some code or even pictures to explain your problem. That's probably the reason for the downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

just one line of code you need to write

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

you have to use

```
addToBackStack
```

so that you can popBack from fragment manager so like this.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(detailFragment, "detail")
                           // Add this transaction to the back stack
                           .addToBackStack()
                           .commit();
```

Comment: I tried, but It's not working, can you give me another way ?

Comment: can you let me see what you tried ?

Comment: and how do you do fragment transitions.

Comment: AFragment:

mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new NofiticationFragment()).commit();

NotificationFragment:

getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

Comment: @LeThanhTan now check answer

Comment: Thank you, but It's also not working.